# Estimating confidence interval of a test score

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, cross-validation, bootstrap

I have two sets of data: A and B. I want to compare the test score estimated using 10-fold cross-validation training in A with the test score when the model trained in A is tested with B. While testing in B, I want to get the confidence interval or some distribution of the test score instead of just a single metric.
I am thinking of two schemes:
1) Use the model trained in each cross validation fold during the training in A to test in B and get 10 different test scores
2) Train a model in A (using all samples, not cross validation) and test in the multiple bootstrap samples from B.

First, I am not sure if I am doing things correctly. If I am correct, which scheme would better represent the variation of the test score in B?